# Simple selenium script hangs on gitlab runner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci-runner

Our application has login screen which works the following way
1>When user lands on the login screen, only `Username` input and `Next` button is visible. `Password` input in hidden.
2>User enters the user name and click on next button. This action shows Password input.
3>User enters Password and press enter to log in.

I am mimicking the same steps using selenium

```
  const emailBy = By.name('Username');
  const passwordBy = By.name('Password');
  const nextBy = By.id("next");
  const navigationBy = By.className('navigation');

  console.log("Locating username");
  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(emailBy)).click();
  console.log("Sending username");
  await driver.findElement(emailBy).sendKeys(email);
        
  console.log("Locating next and then click");
  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(nextBy)).click();
  
  console.log("Sleeping 10 sec");
  await driver.sleep(10000);      

  console.log("finding password");
  const passwdInput = driver.findElement(passwordBy);      

  console.log("checking if password element is visible");
  await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(passwdInput));    

  console.log("sending password and press enter");         
  await driver.findElement(passwordBy).sendKeys(password, Key.RETURN);

  console.log("locating navigation");
  return await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(navigationBy, 2000));
```

When I run this test on my machine pointing to dev web site everything is working.
Then I run the same script on gitlab runner pointing to the same web site, it hangs at the line after `checking if password element is visible`
Gitlab runner is AWS EC2 Linux instance `t3a-medium`. If I changed the instance type to `xlarge` then it working.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "selenium-tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Selenium tests",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --recursive --timeout 500000"
  },      
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chromedriver": "^105.0.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.4.0",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0"
  }  
}
```

GitLab pipeline script

```
- export TestUserName="test"
- export TestPassword="test"
- npm ci --include=dev
- WEBDIRVER_SERVER=http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444 npm test
```

I am not sure what could be the issue here? Why only changing instance type from medium to xlarge works? I am running only one login script.

Comment: Have you tried the other direction using smaller instances? What is the total list of instance type you were already able to test against? And from your description, if you'd ask me to guess, I'd say this is related to performance of _some_ kind.